# How to save an html output as an image in python using the most basic libraries

Tags: python, html

There are many post on how to save an html's visual output as an image in python using libraries such as [`imgkit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imgkit), but most such libraries depend on [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

What is the most basic way to do this, even if this compromises speed or efficiency?

Comment: What's not "basic" about depending on a working tool that has been made for the task?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, I am purely looking for alternatives, as I cannot find any on the web.

Comment: Well, tool recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow, but to get started I would say look into the general direction of headless browsers (here's a list https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) - some of them play nicer with Python than others, of course. It's still an external dependency, but you said "alternatives". :)

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak